# spring-data-mongodb/k8s "Database name must not contain slashes, dots, spaces, quotes, or dollar signs"

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-data-mongodb

I'm at a real loss on this one. I've been attempting to get my application running with a replica set in Kubernetes for awhile. I'm setting: `spring.data.mongodb.uri=${MYAPP_MONGODB}:mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp`
in `application.properties` and using Spring Data to access my objects.

Locally using a local MongoDB container it works fine even if I set the env var to my remote databases locally I can connect to them and work just fine. But when I put the value of MYAPP_MONGODB into k8s secrets when the container boots I get quoted error from the title. The value is like this:

`mongodb://myuser:mypasswd@1.1.1.1:27017,2.2.2.2:27017,3.3.3.3:27017,4.4.4.4:27017,5.5.5.5:27017/myapp`

I [reviewed the source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/SimpleMongoDbFactory.java#L88) and still baffled as to why this is happening. Pulling the secret from the k8s environment it is correct.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: As a for-your-consideration, with a thing like Mongo (or PG or ES), you want a `StatefulSet`, not a `ReplicaSet` since cluster identity and persistent storage being assigned to those stable Pods matters.

Comment: Unless your password is actually `mypassword`, you will want to either separate out the password into its own spring property (highly advised), or ensure you are URL encoding special characters so they don't trip up the URI parser, [as described in the manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-db-factory-java)

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel Thanks for the pointers! The actual password is only numbers & letters with no special characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your secret in k8s might be setup incorrectly. I would try uploading your secrets again and decoding them to make sure they are correct. Careful for random line breaks :)

Comment: Thanks! After pulling it from another box I found the encoding of the secret was wrong

Comment: Please can you clarify this answer a lot better, it's unclear.